# General run error --2147467259 while using childobjects in QTP

Tags: qtp, child-objects

I am trying to print the name of all the links present on a page. I have written the below code-->

```
SystemUtil.Run "Chrome.exe","www.timesofindia.com"
Dim obj, objects,objectnames,i
Set obj = Description.Create
obj("micclass").value = "Link"
objects = Browser("micclass:=browser").Page("micclass:=Page").ChildObjects(obj)
MsgBox Err.number
For i = 0 To obj.Count-1 Step 1
    childnames = objects.getROProperty("innertext")
    print childnames(i)
Next
```

I am getting general run error in line `objects = Browser("micclass:=browser").Page("micclass:=Page").ChildObjects(obj)`

The line `MsgBox Err.number` gives error number `-2147467259`

I tried to find out the cause with error number--2147467259 but didn't get any relevant answer. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your script

- You need to `Set` objects since this is an object
- In the `For` loop you should be looping on `objects.count` not `obj.count`
- In the `For` body you should use `objects(i).GetROProperty` (you forgot to index with `i`)
- In the `Print` statement you're indexing into `childnames` for no reason

After making these changes the script works for me but it's a bit slow, if you're still facing problems it may be that UFT times out while waiting for all the links to show up. If this is the case you can separate the query into several queries (for example where the `innertext` starts with each letter of the alphabet) and run them one after the other.

```
SystemUtil.Run "Chrome.exe","www.timesofindia.com"
Dim obj, objects,objectnames,i
Set obj = Description.Create
obj("micclass").value = "Link"
Set objects = Browser("micclass:=browser").Page("micclass:=Page").ChildObjects(obj)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.number   
End If

Print "Count " & objects.Count
For i = 0 To objects.Count-1 Step 1
    childnames = objects(i).getROProperty("innertext")
    print childnames
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved using on error resume next statement

```
On error resume next
Set desc = description.Create
desc("micClass").value = "WebElement"
set WElementobj = browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(desc)
msgbox welementobj.count
For i = 0 to welementobj.count-1
    print welementobj(i).getroproperty("innertext")
Next
```

The reason this issue comes because of not all the objects would have innertext property.